# Bash script dig command to just return the TTL value

Tags: bash, ttl, dig

I use `dig +short @127.0.0.1 -p 5336 www.google.com` to get the IP address that is being resolved to. I am wondering if there is a similar bash command to just get the ttl value?

Comment: read man dig, and you will find "+[no]ttlid Display [do not display] the TTL when printing the record."

Comment: @darvark I would like to get the TTL value, not avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` and `awk`:

```
# dig www.google.com | grep '^[[:alnum:]]'
www.google.com.         34      IN      A       31.13.73.17
# dig www.google.com | grep '^[[:alnum:]]' | awk '{ print $2 }'
21
#
```